# Is a handwritten scanned signature equivalent to its paper counterpart?

Tags: digital-signature

In terms of Authentication, Integrity and non-repudiation, is a handwritten scanned signature equivalent to its paper counterpart? For example, if you have a paper contract and you obtain a digital copy of it by scanning it, both are equally valid in a court in the event of a conflict?

If not, what are the minimum measures the digital copy need to have to ensure at least the same validity?

Note: I'm more interested in the case of a captured handwritten signature using a tablet or similar, but I think the example is better with the scanned signature because you obtain two versions of the document signed using different tools.

Comment: This will be entirely up to the opinion of your lawyers

Comment: The admissibility of signatures in court is a matter of local law and procedure. It varies by country, and often within countries (an answer from Alabama law doesn't necessarily tell you what a California court would say). Keep in mind that at least in US law, a signature is normally just a piece of evidence; it can be challenged, and doesn't settle the matter (although challenging a signature is uncommon). A contract can be valid without a signature, and a paper signature doesn't automatically make it valid

Comment: @schroeder Technically, it's up to the opinion of the judge; your lawyers just tell you what the judge is likely to say.

Comment: @cpast It's far easier, cheaper, and faster to approach a lawyer for guidance.

Comment: Flagging as off-topic, this is a legal question.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication, Integrity (?) and non-repudiation are digital infosec terms, and what you want are the electronic terms.

Are you in the United States?  The American Bar Association has extensive guidance on this.  Try [Digital Signature Guidelines: Legal Infrastructure for
Certification Authorities and Secure Electronic Commerce](http://www.americanbar.org/content/dam/aba/events/science_technology/2013/dsg_tutorial.pdf) for some basic information (the front talks about scanned wet signatures, but the rest of the document is a 'must read' for the use of digital signatures, which is related but off topic.)